# Vim normal mode in command pallete

Tags: vim

When i write `/` or `:` vim opens command mode - i can write command like:

```
vimgrep /abc/
```

If i click shift+p it fill the previous command.

In this case if i want to change only letter `a` to `b` I should use arrow key until i get to the letter and then rename it

```
abc -> bbc.
```

Is there any faster way - arrow keys are far away and slower to write.

Can I use normal mode when I im in the command pallete(bottom place where i write the commands).

Thank you

Comment: `/` does not open command mode, it is a search.

Comment: You may use `Command Line Window` by hitting `:q` in normal mode to write, edit or reuse commands.

Comment: @dNitro: That should be `q:`, not `:q`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are confusing "command mode" (another name for normal mode) with "command-line mode".
2. `Shift+P` (or simply `P` should insert `P`. Did you mean `<C-p>`?
3. How large is your keyboard for your arrow keys to be "far away"?
4. See `:help cmdline-editing`.

Comment: Yes i meant <C-p>.
When i type Shift-: it opens up the bottom bar where i can type commands: for example :vimgrep /aaa/.

The philisophy of VIM is "Dont use arrow keys" - can I avoid them in this case

Comment: No, the philosophy of Vim (not VIM) is not "Don't use arrow keys". If you want to avoid them remap them, as explained in the help section.

Comment: Yes, the philosophy of vim is not to use the arrow keys. You can read about it on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Vim's *command-line* has limited editing capabilities; for complex edits there, you'd have to use cursor keys. Fortunately, there's a *command-line window*, which allows edits just like in any other buffer.

You'll find the complete explanation at [`:help command-line-window`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#command-line-window). Here's just a quick guide:

- If you already know this is going to be a complex edit, open via `q:` / `q/` instead of `:` / `/`.
- If you only realize this while editing, you can switch via `<C-f>`.